# How to make a method that loops back to the menu in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to get a code that gives several options to pick from and while I can get those to work it ends immediately after when I need it to go back to the options.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, This is the math program");
    System.out.println("Select an application from below: \n");
    System.out.println("(1) pythagoraen");
    System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("(4) Division");
    System.out.println("(5) Exit");
    System.out.println("What is your Choice? ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1) {
        pythagoraen();
        System.out.println(pythagoraen());
    } if (choice == 2) {
        subtraction();
    } if (choice == 3) {
        multiplication();
    } if (choice == 4) {
        division();
    } if (choice == 5){
        exitprogam();
    }
}
public static void subtraction(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int difference;

    System.out.print( "Enter First integer: " );
    number1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print( "Enter Second integer: ");
    number2 = input.nextInt();

    difference = number1 - number2;
    System.out.printf( "The difference is %d\n", difference);

}
```

I've tried several different while loops in an attempt to get it to return to the options but it either endlessly loops or doesn't work.

EDIT: I've added one of the methods to it as an example. the case suggestion doesn't work as I think the format it too different

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, This is the math program");
    System.out.println("Select an application from below: \n");
    System.out.println("(1) pythagoraen");
    System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("(4) Division");
    System.out.println("(5) Exit");
    System.out.println("What is your Choice? ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    while(choice!=5){
        if (choice == 1) {
            pythagoraen();
            System.out.println(pythagoraen());
        } if (choice == 2) {
            subtraction();
        } if (choice == 3) {
            multiplication();
        } if (choice == 4) {
            division();
        } if (choice == 5){
            exitprogam();
        }
}}
```

Here's the only while code i can get to run. it infinitely loops itself.

Comment: What loop did you try to use? You can put it in a while loop till `choice != 5`.

Comment: You also have to handle the case where the user inputs junk instead of a number from 1 to 5.

Comment: Did you hear about `switch (choice) {//...}`?

Comment: @clinomaniac clino i tried that and it wouldn't work. it would just repeat itself constantly.

Comment: @FredK thats not my issue atm. right now i just want to get the code to work

Comment: @TheAuraKing Post your code with the loop you have tried and we'll try to help. Just saying it doesn't work doesn't give any information. The loops can be done in a lot of different ways and if it's not working is probably because you are not doing it right.

Comment: @clinomaniac ah ok. i edited the post and put the only while loop that worked at all for me

Comment: @TheAuraKing Put `choice = input.nextInt();` inside the loop. Also, for choice `1`, you are calling the function twice. Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to achieve what you are looking to do is to use a Do-While loop.  Pay attention to where you ask for the input and then should the choice be equal to your stopping condition, put that as the conditional in the while part of the loop.

While loops will run 0-N times, while Do-While loops always execute 1-N times.  Use this to your advantage.

This is a good reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this but a better way to do it is with the use of a switch. With switch statements you can have a number of execution paths which seem to fit this situation better then the while loop being used. However, a while loop and a switch statement can not really be compared in terms of efficiency as they are fundamentally different, as can be seen in this [article](https://www.quora.com/Is-a-for-or-while-loop-more-effective-than-a-switch-statement-faster). here is how the implementation would look like with switches:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int exitFlag = 0;
    int choice = showMenu();

     do {
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("pythagoraen()");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("subtraction()");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("multiplication()");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("division()");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("exitprogam()");
                exitFlag = 1; 
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Invalid Option()");

                break;
            }
        if (exitFlag != 1) {
            choice = showMenu();    
        }

      }while (choice != 5);
}

private static int showMenu() {
    System.out.println("Hello, This is the math program");
    System.out.println("Select an application from below: \n");
    System.out.println("(1) pythagoraen");
    System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("(4) Division");
    System.out.println("(5) Exit");
    System.out.println("What is your Choice? ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    return choice;
}
```

This is a lot cleaner and easier in the long run for refactoring. For more information on switches please refer to [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html.).

Comment: it doesn't work. all i get is a constant loop. it repeats the menu unless i press 5

Comment: I thought that was you had requested. If not, then just remove the showMenu() call and put the break statement there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the things you need to do over and over again, in a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, This is the math program");
    System.out.println("Select an application from below: \n");
    System.out.println("(1) pythagoraen");
    System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("(4) Division");
    System.out.println("(5) Exit");
    System.out.println("What is your Choice? ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    while(choice!=5){
        if (choice == 1) {
            pythagoraen();
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            subtraction();
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            multiplication();
        }
        else if (choice == 4) {
            division();
        }
        System.out.println("What is your next Choice? ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

If you need the print the menu again, then you can put that also inside the loop. What you are doing here, is asking the user for input and then choosing the operation you want to do. Then at the end, you ask the user again about what to do next. If the user enters 5, the while condition becomes false and it exits the loop.

I also removed the `if choice == 5` condition because the while loop will handle that scenario. Also added else before each if after the first one. That's for efficiency so that it doesn't check rest of the matches if it is matched with the first one.

Comment: Glad to help. If this or any other answer solved your problem, please accept it as the solution and upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this with the while loop

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = input.nextInt();
while(choice != 5) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = input.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1) {
        pythagoraen();
        System.out.println(pythagoraen());
    } if (choice == 2) {
        subtraction();
    } if (choice == 3) {
        multiplication();
    } if (choice == 4) {
        division();
    } if (choice == 5){
        exitprogam();
    }
}
```